# How to assign a value to new attribute to array json objects in java script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have array json elements inside a json. I need add orderCustomerCount in json Objects and assign a value for example 1.

the json is this.

```
    {
    "docs": [
        {
            "vehicle": "moto",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "_id": 34401,
            "service": "programmed"
        },
        {
            "vehicle": "moto",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "_id": 34402,
            "service": "programmed"
        }
    ]
}
```

my code is this

```
listOrders.docs.map((order)=>{
           order.orderCustomerCount = 1
            })
```

but when I return listOrders not show this new attribute orderCustomerCount.

Comment: 1. `Array.map` returns new array
2. Inside map callback you need to `return` something

Comment: Use this to add new property in your array `listOrders.docs.map((order)=> ({...order, orderCustomerCount: 1 }))`.

Answer (score 2):

The array `map` method returns a new array computed by calling the `predicate` in your case `(order) => { order.orderCustomerCount; return undefined; }` (verbose return, functions are equivalent) for each element of the array, and storing the return at the same position **in a new array**.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((n) => 2 * n);
// returns [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

In your case, you return `undefined` in the predicate, because any arrow function has a default return of undefined.

In your case a more appropriate solution would be the array `forEach` method.

```
listOrders.docs.forEach((order)=> {
   order.orderCustomerCount = 1;
});
```

This method only calls the predicate for each element of the array. Because arrays and objects are [reference types](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0?gi=aeca105b7b5e#:%7E:text=Javascript%20has%203%20data%20types,Array%20%2C%20Function%20%2C%20and%20Object%20.), the value of the elements are `mutated` to add the property.

Additionally, you might want to consider whether or whether not you want this. In my own experience, when using objects and arrays, in order to increase predictability, I rarely use assignments, instead I construct new arrays of new objects to ensure the source is not mutated.

```
let newOrders = listOrders.docs.map((order) => {
   let newOrder = {
       ...order, 
       // copy all attributes (properties) of order
       orderCustomerCount: 1,
       // add orderCustomerCount property equal to 1
   };

   return newOrder;
})
```

Note the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

By doing this, the original object is kept as it were, and `newOrders` along with the elements of the array can be modified independently from it.

Answer (score 1):

the `.map()` function creates & returns a new array. You need to do the following:

```js
listOrders.docs = listOrders.docs.map((order) => {
  order.orderCustomerCount = 1
  /* 
     NOTE: This line is important because if you don't return 
     anything from this function, then your array will have an 
     undefined item in it.
  */
  return order; 
})
```